# symfony 3 cookies in a service

Tags: php, cookies, symfony

I need to create a cookie in my service

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $em, RequestStack $request)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->request = $request->getMasterRequest();
}
```

then when I try to call this somewhere inside my service:

```
    echo $this->request->cookies->get('_ga');die;
```

I get cookie that's  created manually by me, but calling ->set(key, val) doesn't save my cookie

```
 $this->request->cookies->set('test', time());
echo $this->request->cookies->get('test');
```

I get time, but cookie only exists once, in scope of this webrequest, if I comment line with ->set then I should see time that isn't changing but I don't see it, because cookie isn't actually stored... any help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try setting the cookies to the **response** Object that is used to build an answer - rather than the *request* which is what you received from the client.

Have a look at this post, it is for Simfony 2 but I assume the principle should be similar for 3.

[Symfony2: setting a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567194/symfony2-setting-a-cookie)

```
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie("user", $user));
```

Moreover I don't think you should set a Cookie in your service, try to pass all required information as business data classes to the service and return a class which can be used to formulate the response object including the cookie.